# How To Install Extended WPF Toolkit?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I just used the NuGet console to install the Extended WPF toolkit to  my Visual Studio 2013 project, but the controls won't show up in the Toolbox. Am I doing something wrong?(I'm new to WPF)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Right click inside the toolbox somewhere, and click "Add Tab". Right click on the new tab you created and click "Choose Items...", from there you can browse to the DLL and add the controls.

Answer (score 4):

After installing via NuGet there is a new folder in the project path named "packages". The DLLs for .NET 4 can be found there below subfolder: packages\Extended.Wpf.Toolkit.3.4.0\lib\net40